# Can you turn an Iterator<T> into an Iterator<&T> efficiently?

Tags: unix, rust, borrow-checker, unix-socket

I've ran into two frustrating problems, it comes from wanting to send messages on a unix socket using [sendmmsg](https://docs.rs/nix/latest/nix/sys/socket/fn.sendmmsg.html) from the nix-crate.

I have some given message which may or may not contain fds.
Nix does most things zero-copy, making it sometimes tricky to work with, making you battle the borrow-checker and type system, both problems come from this function signature:

```
pub fn sendmmsg<'a, I, C, S>(
    fd: RawFd,
    data: impl std::iter::IntoIterator<Item=&'a SendMmsgData<'a, I, C, S>>,
    flags: MsgFlags
) -> Result<Vec<usize>>
    where
        I: AsRef<[IoSlice<'a>]> + 'a,
        C: AsRef<[ControlMessage<'a>]> + 'a,
        S: SockaddrLike + 'a
```

Where SendMmsgData is defined as:

```
pub struct SendMmsgData<'a, I, C, S>
    where
        I: AsRef<[IoSlice<'a>]>,
        C: AsRef<[ControlMessage<'a>]>,
        S: SockaddrLike + 'a
{
    pub iov: I,
    pub cmsgs: C,
    pub addr: Option<S>,
    pub _lt: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a I>,
}
```

And here's the code interfacing with it

```
...
#[inline]
    fn exec_write_many<M>(&mut self, messages: Vec<M>) -> Result<usize, Error>
        where
            M: SocketMessage,
    {
        let mut sent = 0;
        let mut send_message_data = vec![];
        for msg in messages.iter() {
            let mmsg_data = if msg.borrow_fds().is_empty() {
                SendMmsgData {
                    iov: [IoSlice::new(msg.borrow_buf()); 1],
                    cmsgs: vec![],
                    addr: NONE_ADDR,
                    _lt: std::marker::PhantomData::default(),
                }
            } else {
                SendMmsgData {
                    iov: [IoSlice::new(msg.borrow_buf()); 1],
                    cmsgs: vec![ControlMessage::ScmRights(msg.borrow_fds())],
                    addr: NONE_ADDR,
                    _lt: std::marker::PhantomData::default(),
                }
            };
            send_message_data.push(mmsg_data);
        }
        match nix::sys::socket::sendmmsg(self.sock_fd, &send_message_data, MsgFlags::MSG_DONTWAIT) {
            ...
```

Both problems are manageable but come at a performance cost, starting with the major one:
I want to provide the sendmmsg with an iterator created like this instead:

```
...
#[inline]
    fn exec_write_many<M>(&mut self, messages: Vec<M>) -> Result<usize, Error>
        where
            M: SocketMessage,
    {
        let mut sent = 0;
        let sendmmsgs = messages.iter()
            .map(|msg| {
                if msg.borrow_fds().is_empty() {
                    SendMmsgData {
                        iov: [IoSlice::new(msg.borrow_buf()); 1],
                        cmsgs: vec![],
                        addr: NONE_ADDR,
                        _lt: std::marker::PhantomData::default(),
                    }
                } else {
                    SendMmsgData {
                        iov: [IoSlice::new(msg.borrow_buf()); 1],
                        cmsgs: vec![ControlMessage::ScmRights(msg.borrow_fds())],
                        addr: NONE_ADDR,
                        _lt: std::marker::PhantomData::default(),
                    }
                }
            });
        match nix::sys::socket::sendmmsg(self.sock_fd, sendmmsgs, MsgFlags::MSG_DONTWAIT) {
            ...
```

But since SendMmsgData is owned by the iterator I get this:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@socks/src/buffered_writer.rs:146:18: 162:14] as FnOnce<(&M,)>>::Output == &SendMmsgData<'_, _, _, _>`
    --> socks/src/buffered_writer.rs:163:56
     |
163  |         match nix::sys::socket::sendmmsg(self.sock_fd, sendmmsgs, MsgFlags::MSG_DONTWAIT) {
     |               --------------------------               ^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found struct `SendMmsgData`
     |               |
     |               required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = note: expected reference `&SendMmsgData<'_, _, _, _>`
                   found struct `SendMmsgData<'_, [IoSlice<'_>; 1], Vec<ControlMessage<'_>>, ()>`
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Iterator` for `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, M>, [closure@socks/src/buffered_writer.rs:146:18: 162:14]>`
note: required by a bound in `nix::sys::socket::sendmmsg`
    --> /home/gramar/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/nix-0.24.2/src/sys/socket/mod.rs:1456:40
     |
1456 |     data: impl std::iter::IntoIterator<Item=&'a SendMmsgData<'a, I, C, S>>,
     |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `nix::sys::socket::sendmmsg`
```

It's pretty frustrating as for `Options` for example I can just call `as_ref()` to turn the inner `T` to `&T` but I can't figure out how to do that with the iterator which makes me allocate another vector and loop through all messages to be sent.

The second smaller issue is the `cmsgs`. The type-system disallows using an array, since one branch will have the type `[_ ;1]` and the other `[_ ;0]`. The empty Vec causes no allocations, while the vec with one item will cause an allocation.

Both problems have me running into the same issue. I can't figure out how to create a wrapper struct and just implement `IntoIterator<Item=&'a SendMmsgData<'a, I, C, S>>` and `AsRef<[ControlMessage<'a>]>` respectively because both requires me to return a reference that will be created in the function body, as my datastructure is not on the form `SendMmsgData` or `ControlMessage`, and both of those reference some other piece of memory, in my case I would have to create a struct with an owned buffer and an internal reference to that (internal reference to self) which creates other problems.

Any ideas of how I can do this without the extra loop/allocations?

Ps. On measurements, doing this is around a 10% performance hit when messages do not have fds because of how that syscall works, with a 2% performance increase on the case of only having messages with fds:

```
if msg.borrow_fds().is_empty() {
                SendMmsgData {
                    iov: [IoSlice::new(msg.borrow_buf()); 1],
                    cmsgs: [ControlMessage::ScmRights(&[])],
                    addr: NONE_ADDR,
                    _lt: std::marker::PhantomData::default(),
                }
            } else {
                SendMmsgData {
                    iov: [IoSlice::new(msg.borrow_buf()); 1],
                    cmsgs: [ControlMessage::ScmRights(msg.borrow_fds())],
                    addr: NONE_ADDR,
                    _lt: std::marker::PhantomData::default(),
                }
            };
```

I could just use the libc crate directly, and if I can't solve this in a better way I'll have to do that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with your first problem is that `sendmmsg` could call `next` on the iterator `n` times, getting references to `n` `SendMsgData`s that all have to live somewhere. Because you can't know what `n` is, *all* `SendMsgData`s have to live somewhere, so you'll have to buffer them in a `Vec`. This could be fixed by changing the API of `sendmmsg` to take either owned or borrowed `SendMsgData`s, but you obviously don't have control over that.

The `cmsgs` issue, I think, can be helped though. You can create your own `Option`-like wrapper that lives purely on the stack and that implements `AsRef` based on whether it contains a value or not:

```
struct ControlMessage<'a>(std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>);

enum CMsgWrapper<'a> {
    Empty,
    Msg(ControlMessage<'a>),
}

impl<'a> AsRef<[ControlMessage<'a>]> for CMsgWrapper<'a> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[ControlMessage<'a>] {
        match self {
            CMsgWrapper::Empty => &[],
            CMsgWrapper::Msg(cmsg) => std::slice::from_ref(cmsg),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I'm gonna interface with libc directly on the other part but this was a nice solution for what can be fixed without changing the API, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like in the accepted answer was said, your temporary struct should live somewhere. As I see, you accept input parameter by value, so you can probably modify them. Yes, I propose some "dirty" solution that does not look good even for me, but when performance really matters, we can try it.

So the idea is to put `SendMmsgData` structs into your message parameters as `Option<SendMmsgData>` and make `SocketMessage` trait have `fn get_send_mmsg_data(&mut self) -> &SendMmsgData`.

[Here is example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=deafc4c1d75569a483e92edc824bc2f4)

And yes, it's better to make PR into rust std library to chane `sendmmsg` interface making it accept references.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered that OP may control `M`.